# The Active Directory integrated DNS zone _msdcs.COMPANY.LOCAL was not found

Tags: active-directory

Recently we renamed our domain from single domain name COMPANY to COMPANY.LOCAL due to multiple problems. However now I get this information from BPA.

> Issue: The Active Directory integrated
>   DNS zone _msdcs.COMPANY.LOCAL was not
>   found.
>
> Impact: DNS queries for the Active
>   Directory integrated zone
>   _msdcs.COMPANY.LOCAL might fail.
>
> Resolution: Restore the Active
>   Directory integrated DNS zone
>   _msdcs.COMPANY.LOCAL.

Clearly there is no _msdcs.COMPANY.LOCAL as there is only old one _msdcs.COMPANY however when i check under COMPANY there is no _msdsc, but there is one when i check inside COMPANY.LOCAL. So it seems to me that _msdcs.COMPANY.LOCAL should use the one that is inside COMPANY.LOCAL? Should it not? Should I try to `recreate` it by hand (since it wasn't created on domain rename).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating new forward lookup zone with correct name `_msdcs.forestname.local` and restarting the `netlogon service` helped me out ;-) Zone was populated with right entries.

Quick and easy solution. Hope it helps someone out!

Answer (score -1):

How did you rename your domain exactly ?

Really you should have created a new domain, then migrated everything over.
This would be a pain to do, but everything would work properly - trying to rename a domain by hand is going to get you into all sorts of problems.

I would suggest undoing what ever you have done and then look at migrating to a new domain

Comment: Well I did it normal Microsoft way. Renaming domain is supported and many have done it. We couldn't just migrate stuff because we had SharePoint which had history and some custom made apps for it (like timesheet) that with new users would be broken. Hence the rename.

Comment: @Jon, renaming domains is fully supported since Windows Server 2003. It can be a pain and it may break things, but it can *definitely* be done, in a documented and supported way.

Comment: Thanks Massimo, I wasn't aware of that, I was always under the impression that you needed to build a new domain - Windows 2000 thing perhaps ?